# example on moving fengyuanchen cropper image to local file system

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

I tried multiple ways to do it. I have tech stack as  bootstrap /php/ mysql. I need to store profile images of user in file system or database. Can anyone help me with a sample code?

I could bring myself to level that cropped file is generated and can be downloaded. But further I am stuck in saving them to file system or database.

```
                 <!-- Content -->
                            <!-- Default box -->
                  <div class="box collapsed-box">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                      <h3 class="box-title">Family Details</h3>

                      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" title="Collapse">
                          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                         <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                          <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>-->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <!-- <h3 class="page-header">Demo:</h3> -->
                    <div class="img-container">
                      <img id="image" src="" alt="Picture">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <!-- <h3 class="page-header">Preview:</h3> -->
                    <div class="docs-preview clearfix">
                      <div class="img-preview preview-lg"></div>

                    </div>              

                  <div class="docs-buttons">                  
                    <div class="btn-group">

                      <!-- upload -->
                      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-upload" for="inputImage" title="Upload image file">
                        <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="inputImage" name="file" accept="image/*">
                        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Import image with Blob URLs">
                          <span class="fa fa-upload"></span>
                          Browse Image
                        </span>
                      </label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-crop">
                     <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="getCroppedCanvas">
                        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;getCroppedCanvas&quot;)">
                          Get Cropped Canvas
                        </span>
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="getCroppedCanvas" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 160, &quot;height&quot;: 90 }">
                        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;getCroppedCanvas&quot;, { width: 160, height: 90 })">
                          160&times;90
                        </span>
                      </button>-->
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="getCroppedCanvas" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 320, &quot;height&quot;: 320 }">
                        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;getCroppedCanvas&quot;, { width: 320, height: 320 })">
                          Preview
                        </span>
                      </button>

                    <!-- Show the cropped image in modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade docs-cropped" id="getCroppedCanvasModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="getCroppedCanvasTitle" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="getCroppedCanvasTitle">Cropped</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body"></div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="download" href="javascript:void(0);" download="cropped.jpg">Save</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal -->
                  </div><!-- /.docs-buttons -->
              </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            <!-- add photo ends -->
```

==== PHP code

```
        $target_dir = "../apppage/memImage/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"][$filename]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to narrow the HTML code that you show to specific relevant portions, and to show some of the PHP code that does the work of moving the files.

Comment: with click on save button i get a jpj fle named cropped.jpg is downloaded. what i need to do is on click it should save the file in an designated folder. i had written an php which accepts file name and moves that filename and move that file to designated location